# Selection sort implementation in C++ iterator approach

Tags: c++, sorting, iterator

I am trying to learn the C++ way of writing code. I was wondering if this code could be improved or if there are any major mistakes. Is it ok how I name the variables?

```
template<typename Iterator, typename Comparator>
void selection_sort(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Comparator comparator) {
    for (; begin != end; ++begin) {

        auto min = std::min_element(begin, end, comparator);

        if (comparator(*min, *begin)) {
            std::iter_swap(min, begin);
        }
    }
}
template<typename Iterator>
void selection_sort(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type value_type;

    selection_sort(begin, end, std::less<value_type>());
}
```

Comment: This code looks really good. Good job

Comment: Why did you decide to have the if statement guarding the swap?  This might be optimizing for a rare case.  I think you can weaken the iterators to be ForwardIterators.  The STL standardizes on using "first" and "last" for the names of the iterators (not "begin" and "end").  The variable "min" should probably be labeled as const.  Otherwise looks good.  Nice job.